# loading script to populate database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to load a script to populate a database. I have created the database and the user, and now I just need to create the tables from the script.

I am using this command from the cmd:

source C:\Temp\filename.sql;

and I either get a message indicating error 2 (that the file cannot be read) or 'No previous outfile available, you must give a file name!'

I have looked over questions relating to this, but have not found a solution.

Please assist,
mehmeh

Answer (score 7):

In MySQL, backslash is the escape character. So, in your path, replace backslashes by slashes or double backslashes. This gives

```
SOURCE C:/Temp/filename.sql;
```

or

```
SOURCE C:\\Temp\\filename.sql;
```

Comment: Hi Eric, that is exactly what i just read elsewhere and tired, and it works!! thank you very much for the assistance!